# Error - fi:command not found

Tags: unix

if 0 -eq 0 then

echo uploaded

fi

fi: command not found

why?, can some one oint out the misake?. I am very new to unix scripting.

I amusing 'csh'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for using `fi` and, as you ask in a comment for using `-eq` and `-gt` is all `sh` syntax. `sh` syntax will work fine in `bash`, in `ksh`, in actual `sh` (should you ever get ahold of it) but **not in `csh`**.

**CSH USES TOTALLY DIFFERENT SYNTAX**

Either switch shells or switch syntax to that described in the [csh manpage](http://dell9.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?csh+1).

Specifically, in csh you would say:

```
if ($var1 > 0) then
  echo positive
else if ($var1 == 0) then
  echo zero
else
  echo negative
endif
```

Almost every Linux tutorial and most general unix tutorials will show you `sh`-style syntax, not `csh`-style syntax. If you continue to use a `csh` variant, you should be aware that you are probably making life hard for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
if (0 == 0) echo uploaded
```

Comment: I tried, it says if: Expression syntax

Comment: if [ 0 -eq 0 ]; then
echo uploaded
fi
 O/P is if: Expression Syntax

Comment: @user2052801 Fixed, didn't realize you were using `csh`.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me an example for using -gt with two variables. I see if : Expression syntax for that

Comment: @user2052801 use `if ($number > 5) echo number is more than five`.